# How to vertically center the text of a link button

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I couldn't figure out how to vertically center the text of a link button when the text goes too long.

[as shown in this example:](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uhEpJ)

the first button's text aligned top, I couldn't get it in the middle.

line-height needs to be maintained in 22px or to make 2 lines fit in a single button.

Please help

Thank you in advance

Comment: @Notulysses: YES, it works like a champ, thank you so much, much appreciated, sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `display` `inline-block` with `table-cell` and `vertical-align:text-top` with `middle` in the `.location_button` CSS class

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JAnEc)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a line break to force the code to break?

```
<td class="button_cell">
    <a class="location_button" href="#">Kitchenerfa<br>sdfasdf King</a>
</td>
```